# Unable to convert mongoose Buffer data array to string?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an image that is saved in MongoDB in the form binary data. But, whenever I fetch the image data from the database, it is returned in the form of an array. I want it to be in the form of base64. I have tried many solutions but nothing seems to work.

```
"type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
      137,
      80,
      78,
      71,
      13,
      10,
      26,
      10,
      0,
      0]
```

This is the data array returned.

Comment: How are you saving the image in the DB?

Comment: Using mongoose schema type Buffer and a npm package called multer.

Comment: Check this out [uploading-files-using-multer-nodejs](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/uploading-files-using-multer-nodejs/)

Comment: Thanks. I will see